If f is differentiable on [a,b] then it is Lipschitz of order 1?
I understand how to prove the weaker case where you add the hypothesis that f is continuously differentiable on [a,b] and slightly less weaker , when f’ is bounded. However, to disprove the statement I think that the key is finding a differentiable function on [a,b] which has an unbounded first derivative on [a,b] but I am unsure that is even possible.
These ideas come from the fact that for any pair of numbers $x,y$ in $[a,b]$ since f is differentiable on $[a,b]$ the Mean Value Theorem on $[x,y]$ allows me to see that $|f(x)-f(y)| = |f’(z)||x-y|, z = Z(x,y)$

Functions like $x^2 \sin(1/x^2)$ are differentiable with unbounded derivative.

But it is not unbounded on a closed set

@Alejandro Martin also intends the function to evaluate to $0$ at $x = 0$. Such a function is differentiable everywhere, but does indeed have an unbounded derivative, on any non-trivial closed interval containing $0$.

Oh, right. I though the denominator inside the sine was x, because in that case it is bounded right?

By "Lipschitz of order $1$", don't your rather mean "Lipschitz" (i.e. Hölder of order $1$)?

On any non-trivial closed interval containing $0$, MartinR's example is not even Lipschitz. This answers your question.
